# Get file name before downloading

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, wget

I'm trying to build a scraper in python and only want to download new episodes of a podcast. The problem is that I don't know what the file names will be until after the file is downloaded. Is there a way to get the file name before downloading?

```
def download(path, fileName):
    if(not os.path.exists(fileName)):
        wget.download(path)
```

Comment: What is the site?

Comment: thetalkingmachines.com

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that url to podcast redirects you to another url. Then you can use `requests` to get the final url

```
import requests
final_url = requests.head(url_to_podcast, allow_redirects=True).url
```

and then get the filename from the final url

```
filename = final_url.split('/')[-1]
```